# rmarkdown: new behaviour when knitting pdf documents

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc, pdflatex

I tried to knit an old rmarkdown document to pdf recently. In the document, I had used the tilde symbol to denote a non-breaking space, e.g. 'Figure~2'. This syntax now seems to behave differently, now it prints 'Figure~2' verbatim, with the tilde printed in the document. There are many other differences, for instance % would once be interpreted as a comment, now it is printed.

I'm using Debian stretch with RStudio-1.2.1335. I can't find any documentation of this change in rmarkdown, pandoc or RStudio. Does anyone know what caused this change? Or how to revert to the old behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: I know this behaviour and I actually cannot remember when it was different. Anyhow, what I do now is to use `\p{~}` which I have defined as `\newcommand{\p}[1]{\protect{#1}}`.

Comment: I just researched a bit more. The HTML entity `&nbsp;` might work as well.

Comment: And the pandoc solution is to escape a space: `Word\ Word`. Then a tilde will appear in the tex file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The pandoc solution is to simply escape a space:

   `This is a short\ sentence.`

   Then a tilde will appear in the tex output.
2. What might work as well is `$nbsp;`:

   `This is a short&nbsp;sentence.`
3. And if you really like your TeX then use `\protect{~}`:

   `This is a short\protect{~}sentence.`

Comment: Or use a Lua filter to replace all tides with non-breaking spaces: `function Str (s) return pandoc.Str(s.text:gsub('~', ' ')) end`